# CakePHP 3: Collection: listNested

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to flatten a tree structure with CakePHP's listNested function as explained here: [http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake\Collection\Collection::listNested](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::listNested)

I've tried the given example, but I don't get the expected result as in the example. What am I doing wrong or is this a bug in the listNested function?

My code:

```
$data = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'parent_id' => null,
            'name' => 'Birds',
            'children' => [
                ['id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Land Birds', 'children' => []],
                ['id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Eagle', 'children' => []],
                ['id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Seagull', 'children' => []],
            ]
        ],
        [
            'id' => 6,
            'parent_id' => null,
            'name' => 'Fish',
            'children' => [
                ['id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 6, 'name' => 'Clown Fish', 'children' => []],
            ]
        ]
    ];

$collection = new Collection($data);

$flatList = $collection->listNested();

debug($flatList->toArray());
```

My result:

```
[
    (int) 0 => [
        'id' => (int) 5,
        'parent_id' => (int) 6,
        'name' => 'Clown Fish',
        'children' => []
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'id' => (int) 6,
        'parent_id' => null,
        'name' => 'Fish',
        'children' => [
            (int) 0 => [
                'id' => (int) 5,
                'parent_id' => (int) 6,
                'name' => 'Clown Fish',
                'children' => []
            ]
        ]
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        'id' => (int) 4,
        'parent_id' => (int) 1,
        'name' => 'Seagull',
        'children' => []
    ]
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
    ['id' => 1, 'parent_id' => null, 'name' => 'Birds'],
    ['id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Land Birds'],
    ['id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Eagle'],
    ['id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Seagull'],
    ['id' => 6, 'parent_id' => null, 'name' => 'Fish'],
    ['id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 6, 'name' => 'Clown Fish']
]
```

Comment: seems you're right. Or at least the documentation is misleading. Consider opening a ticket